# Here Fleet Telematics API In Maintenace

Tags: here-api

I intend to use the Here Fleet Telematics API.
On the HERE platform [Documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation), HERE Fleet Telematics API is shown as 'In Maintenace'. Is it just temporary or the API would be deprecated in the future? I was not able to find pricing details for this api on the [pricing](https://www.here.com/get-started/pricing)

As of now I am able to access the fleet telematics APIs. I reached out to the Sales team, but they were not able to answer my query and asked me to ask it here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Fleet Telematics API is planned to be deprecated in Q4 2023.

Depending on the use case you are about to use these services will replace the Fleet Telematics API:
Waypoints Sequencing v8
Route Matching v8
Map Attributes v8
Geofencing v8
Routing v8

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34271991)